# Need to repaint my exterior, a couple of question with painting

Tags: paint, paint-removal

My exterior need a re-painting, I have got a couple of question here:

1. How do I find a paint that matches my exterior? Using naked eye is bit unreliable.
2. Do I need to scratch the old paint off before re-applying new one?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to touch up sections without a whole house painting...

In an inconspicuous area, use a razor blade and skim off a small section.  Take it to Home Depot and let them use their paint matching machine. Then have them mix an exterior paint for you.

I did this for an interior wall once and I could never tell the difference after it dried.

I would scrap and prime the bubbled portions of the wall.

My 2 cents

Comment: Any other home improvement or paint store can do color matching, too.